# java.lang.IllegalStateException during redraw with SLD

Tags: sld, geotools

I would like to draw this border line on polygons:

[image: I Would like to draw this line:]

But sometimes when zooming/redrawing I get this Exception:

```
feb. 08, 2023 1:01:37 EM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorEvent
ALLVARLIG: null
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.EmptyIterator.next(EmptyIterator.java:40)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.drawWithGraphicsStroke(StyledShapePainter.java:554)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paintLineStyle(StyledShapePainter.java:344)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paint(StyledShapePainter.java:291)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3718 )
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:4086)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

My SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ogc:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
<ogc:NamedLayer>
<ogc:Name>MilArea_polygon</ogc:Name>
<ogc:UserStyle>
  <ogc:Name>MilArea_polygon</ogc:Name>
  <ogc:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <ogc:Name>name</ogc:Name>
    <ogc:Rule>
      <ogc:Name>Single symbol</ogc:Name>
      <ogc:LineSymbolizer>
        <ogc:Stroke>
          <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</ogc:CssParameter>
          <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</ogc:CssParameter>
          <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</ogc:CssParameter>
          <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</ogc:CssParameter>
        </ogc:Stroke>
      </ogc:LineSymbolizer>
      <ogc:LineSymbolizer>
        <ogc:Stroke>
          <ogc:GraphicStroke>
            <ogc:Graphic>
              <ogc:Mark>
                <ogc:WellKnownName>shape://vertline</ogc:WellKnownName>
                <ogc:Fill>
                  <ogc:CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</ogc:CssParameter>
                </ogc:Fill>
                <ogc:Stroke>
                  <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</ogc:CssParameter>
                </ogc:Stroke>
              </ogc:Mark>
              <ogc:Size>10</ogc:Size>
              <ogc:Rotation>45.0</ogc:Rotation>
            </ogc:Graphic>
          </ogc:GraphicStroke>
          <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</ogc:CssParameter>
        </ogc:Stroke>
        <ogc:PerpendicularOffset>-3</ogc:PerpendicularOffset>
      </ogc:LineSymbolizer>
    </ogc:Rule>
  </ogc:FeatureTypeStyle>
</ogc:UserStyle>
</ogc:NamedLayer>
</ogc:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

After debug (FINE): getting two exceptions:

```
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM java.awt.Component isMixingNeeded
FIN: containing window = org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapFrame[frame2,-1920,765,1500x800,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=FlygInfo SE, simple mapviewer,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,7,30,1486x763,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]; has h/w descendants = false; has l/w descendants = true; disposing = false
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.data.util.CRSConverterFactory createConverter
FIN: CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.data.util.InterpolationConverterFactory createConverter
FIN: InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory getShape
FIN: Exception while scanning for the appropriate mark factory java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: shape://vertline
at org.geotools.renderer.style.svg.RenderableSVGCache.getRenderableSVG(RenderableSVGCache.java:81)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.svg.SVGMarkFactory.getShape(SVGMarkFactory.java:49)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getShape(SLDStyleFactory.java:1367)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createMarkStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:633)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:593)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getGraphicStroke(SLDStyleFactory.java:922)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createLineStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:442)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:326)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:291)
at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:265)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:3008)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2891)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2666)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2286)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:919)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:94)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:1)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setAutoCommit
FIN:   setAutoCommit = true
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore closeSafe
FIN: CLOSE CONNECTION
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl paintLabels
FIN: TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl paintLabels
FIN: PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl paintLabels
FIN: REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer paint
FIN: Style cache hit ratio: 0.9426508071367884 , hits 4438, requests 4708
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM java.awt.Container mixOnReshaping
FIN: this = javax.swing.JLabel[,5,5,16x16,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=20,height=20],preferredSize=,defaultIcon=file:/C:/Program%20Files/workspaces/testWorkspace/jdbcconnection28/target/classes/org/geotools/jdbcconnection/ico/klar.png,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM java.awt.Component isMixingNeeded
FIN: this = javax.swing.JLabel[,5,5,16x16,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=20,height=20],preferredSize=,defaultIcon=file:/C:/Program%20Files/workspaces/testWorkspace/jdbcconnection28/target/classes/org/geotools/jdbcconnection/ico/klar.png,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]; areBoundsValid = false
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM java.awt.Container mixOnReshaping
FIN: this = javax.swing.JLabel[,7,5,16x16,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=20,height=20],preferredSize=,defaultIcon=file:/C:/Program%20Files/workspaces/testWorkspace/jdbcconnection28/target/classes/org/geotools/jdbcconnection/ico/klar.png,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
feb. 10, 2023 6:53:54 FM java.awt.Component isMixingNeeded
FIN: this = javax.swing.JLabel[,7,5,16x16,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=...
```

2:nd

```
FIN: CLOSE CONNECTION
feb. 10, 2023 7:32:13 FM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorEvent
ALLVARLIG: null
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.EmptyIterator.next(EmptyIterator.java:40)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.drawWithGraphicsStroke(StyledShapePainter.java:554)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paintLineStyle(StyledShapePainter.java:344)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paint(StyledShapePainter.java:291)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3718)
at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:4086)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

feb. 10, 2023 7:32:13 FM org.geotools.renderer.label.LabelCacheImpl paintLabels
FIN: TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
```

I have also tried with line instead of shape://vertline, but it is the same.
I've checked the geometries with PostGis (ST_IsValid), without any negative results.

When I change to a simple solid polygon with a simple line border style def. I don't get any exceptions.

It mostly happens when I zoom in to greater scales (>1:60.000), but it could also happen when I pan in scale e.g 1:400.000...

If I convert the polygons to lines there is no problem.

Comment: it looks like one of your geometries is empty, possibly after simplification for rendering. Can you turn debug up and try to trigger it again

Comment: I've updated my initial question with more info.

Comment: I don't think the 1st exception is relevant, I suspect that something odd is happening to your polygon when it's transformed for rendering, you'll either need to attach a debugger and see if you can see what, or generate a small self contained example that shows the error that others can run to investigate in a bug report

Comment: I've tried with several polygon layers and it is the same with them when using the above SLD file.

Comment: we still need a small self contained example if anyone is going to investigate

Comment: what are you meaning with "a small self contained example"?

Comment: a few 10s of lines of code that when compiled and run shows the issue